# How can I avoid quotes in useDelimeter() method?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a file and I need to get objects from it. File example:

```
"Dude1", 17, student
Dude2, 23, worker
"Dude, Dude", 11, student
```

What delimeter I need to use to avoid quotation marks and don't split sting in it?

It would be perfect to get this as a result for this example:

```
Object1:
name: Dude1
age: 17
work: student

Object2:
name: Dude2
age: 23
work: worker

Object3:
name: Dude, Dude
age: 11
work: student
```

I know how to get objects from a file. I understand that I need to use regex in delimiter, but I don't understand what exactly it should be like

Comment: If this is CSV, you need a parser.  A "delimiter" isn't how it works.  And your example #3 is wrong, there should be a comma in the `name` field.

Comment: You need a csv api such as OpenCsv. That supports binding to beans too